# To convert foreach to linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, foreach

How to convert the following `c# foreach` to `linq` code ?

```
var structure = "names structure";
var names = "name1, name2, name3";
foreach (var name in namesList)
{
     BuildPage(name, structure, names);
}
```

Comment: I would say that there is no point, you shouldn't refactor foreach-loops that *does things* into LINQ, only foreach-loops that is in reality a query, ie. a foreach loop that adds things to a list. You're not doing that, so I would say leave it. **Why** do you want to convert it to LINQ?

Comment: namesList.ForEach(name => BuildPage(name, structure, names))

Comment: But again, as others have said, this is only a foreach.

Comment: Also, consider using a different nickname than "StackOverflow".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going against the grain, you can use the `.ForEach` loop which takes an `Action` parameter.

```
namesList.ForEach(x => BuildPage(x, structure, names));
```

But yeah, what `Rene Vogt` said.

Comment: To continue the grain: `List<T>.ForEach()` is not a part of LINQ, it's simply an instance method of `List<T>` :)

Comment: @RenéVogt Turns out [you're right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx). I didn't know that, I always thought it was a LINQ thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to convert this to LINQ.

What you do here is to start an action/call a method for each `name` in `namesList` (just as your code says). So you want to create side effects for all elements in your collection.

LINQ has a *functional* approach. So it's purpose is to take values of one set and create another set by *projection, filtering and/or aggregation*, but not to create *side effects* on those elements.

Your code as it is is readable and effective, there is no need to turn this into a misused LINQ statement.

Comment: I've once started using .ForEach in Linq, but I stopped very fast. It just didn't help and did make the code less readable